# how to compile a java file which is in a jar and then re-create the jar

Tags: jar, extract

I have a jar file (Gestp.jar) . And I have some .Java files (which are web applications) within the jar file

I need to modify a particular .Java file . And then re-create the Jar file and deploy it in a server.

I have extracted the jar file , and did the modification to the .Java file. But unable to create the .class file with the changes , in eclipse as it is a web application.

Please help.

Thanks in advance,
Aditya.T